# Part of object isn't smooth, but polygonal

Tags: rendering, modifiers, eevee-render-engine

I've been creating a very simple wand. My problem is that there's a part of the handle that looks polygonal. How do I get rid of it?

I was rendering in EEVEE, but same thing happens in Cycles

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using Blender 3.0.0. I applied the scale etc (don't know if that could work) and I also used a *Subdivide* modifier. You can see my UV map in picture

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shade smooth, try increasing the normal angle. You can do this by going into object data properties > normals > auto smooth, then increasing the angle

Comment: Tried it, sadly didn't work